# Python: List of addressable IP addresses

Tags: python, network-programming, cidr

What's the most Pythonic way to create a list of the addressable IP addresses given a netaddr IPRange or netaddr IPNetwork.

If I use these, then it includes subnet and broadcast addresses:

```
hosts = list(IPRange('212.55.64.0','212.55.127.255'))
hosts = IPNetwork('192.168.0.1/24')
```

So what I need for say IPNetwork(192.168.0.0/27) is a list from 192.168.0.1 to 192.168.0.31 note that 192.168.0.0 and 192.168.0.32 must not be included.

**EDIT**

Thanks for info on how to do it with IPy. Does anybody know if it can be done with netaddr?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing a bit of research I found this way:

```
 l = list(netaddr.IPNetwork('192.168.0.0/27').iter_hosts())
```

Answer (score 1):

The following is a quick script to do what you want using netaddr
(Python 2.7, linux)

```
from netaddr import *

def addr(address, prefix):
    ip = IPNetwork(address)
    ip.prefixlen = int(prefix)
    return ip

myip = addr('192.168.0.0', '27')

for usable in myip.iter_hosts():
    print '%s' % usable
```